# SQL Server 2012 or 2014 Failover Cluster - Change Instance Port Number

Tags: sql-server-2012, instance, cluster-computing, sql-server-2014, port-number

I am trying to change the randomly-assigned TCP Port Number for my Two-Node SQL Server Failover Cluster to a static value (a value already setup in our firewalls, etc.)

I have seen a number of posts from various sources on this topic, all of which jump on pointing you at articles for SQL Server 2005 and 2008 and the old Cluster.exe tool (which I don't think is currently delivered).

You can't just use SQL Server Configuration Manager to change TCP Port in a Failover Cluster environment.

Does anyone have insight into how to assign a static port for a named instance on a failover cluster of 2012 generation or newer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server configuration is off-topic.

Comment: I guess I should have made it clear that I wanted to script (program) the configuration of this server.